# How to replace some elements in 2d array with the elemnts from 1d array, if these elements depend on the row of 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't konw how to get rid of the `for` loop in the following function. It takes 1d array `phi` of `shape=(N,)` and two 1d arrays `phi0` and `phi1` of `shape=(M,)` and returns 2d array `r` of `shape=(M,N)`.

```
def circ_pert(phi, phi0, phi1):

    M, N = phi0.size, phi.size
    r = np.empty((M,N))
    r[:] = 1

    for row in range(M):
        r[row, (phi>phi0[row]) & (phi<phi1[row])] = 1 + some_func(phi[(phi>phi0[row]) & (phi<phi1[row])])

    return r
```

In other words it replaces those elements of `r`, which corespond to `phi` in the intrval from `phi0` to `phi1` but this interval depends on the row of `r`.

I know, how to do it duplicating `phi` up to the  `shape=(M,N)`. But it looks so ugly. Probably there is some nice numpy way?

Comment: Is every row guaranteed to have the same number of elements that fulfil the condition `(phi > phi0[row]) & (phi < phi1[row])`? What is `some_func`?

Comment: Also you can just initialize `r = np.ones(...)` instead of initializing to empty and then assigning `1` to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `phi0` and `phi1` to column-vectors (with `.shape == (M, 1)`), numpy will broadcast comparison operations with `phi` to a `(M, N)` array.

Say:

```
phi = np.array([0.79082882, 0.44095191, 0.07705772, 0.94666686, 0.700526  ])
phi0 = np.array([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
phi1 = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
```

We have:

```
gt_comparison = phi > phi0.reshape((-1, 1))
# array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
#        [ True, False, False,  True,  True],
#        [ True, False, False,  True, False]])


lt_comparison = phi < phi1.reshape((-1, 1))
# array([[False, False,  True, False, False],
#        [False,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [False,  True,  True, False,  True],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Then, you can simply do:

```
result = np.ones((M, N))
result[gt_comparison & lt_comparison] = ...
```

To take the indices of `phi` where columns of your comparison are `True`, you can use `np.where` to get the column indices that are `True` for every row, and then use that to index into the required elements of `phi`

```
_, col_indices = np.where(gt_comparison & lt_comparison)
phi_vals = phi[col_indices]
```

Then, call your `some_func` and assign like so:

```
result[gt_comparison & lt_comparison] = 1 + some_func(phi_vals)
```

Assuming your `some_func` simply squares the input:

```
def some_func(x):
    return x**2
```

this gives the following `result`, which is identical to what is returned by your function:

```
array([[1.        , 1.        , 1.00593789, 1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.19443859, 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.49073668],
       [1.62541022, 1.        , 1.        , 1.89617814, 1.        ]])
```

With `N = 10`, varying the value of `M` shows that the numpy approach is significantly faster than looping.
[image]